# Where did the functionality of /var/log/dmesg go in xenial 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, logging, dmesg

`/var/log/dmesg` was a useful boot time `dmesg` dump. I can’t find that any more in Ubuntu 16.04. Is it somewhere else?

(`/var/log/kern.log*` is limited; it catches kernel messages only after the logging daemon is running. Further is it cumbersome to find the right kern.log.X.gz file where the last boot happened. (It might have been rotated away, too.))

Comment: Does `dmesg | head -n 100` give you the boot time messages you want? If so, `unbuffer dmesg | head -n 100` will do it in color.

Comment: If `/var/log/kern.log*` is limited try `/var/log/syslog*` instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To show the output from the last boot, you can still use the command `dmesg`.

However, Ubuntu 16.04 (in fact all Ubuntus >=15.04) use `systemd` which has a logging daemon, `journald` and an interface with highly flexible access to logged data: `journalctl`. You can see a log of the last boot equivalent to `dmesg`:

```
journalctl -k
```

From [`journalctl` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html):

> `-k, --dmesg` Show only kernel messages. This implies -b and adds the match "_TRANSPORT=kernel"

all `dmesg` output in the last 2 hours

```
journalctl -k --since "2 hours ago"
```

all of the journal since last boot

```
journalctl -b
```

list boots in the journal

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

to set up persistent logging, you need to configure `journald` - by default its log is written non-persistently to `/run/systemd/journal` (a binary file - no use trying to read it) and no data is available before the current boot. To set up persistent logging, edit the file `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and uncomment the line `#Storage=auto` and change `auto` to `persistent`. Use your favourite text editor or

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/#Storage=auto/Storage=persistent/' /etc/systemd/journald.conf
```

Then you must restart the service (or reboot)

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Having enabled persistent logging, you will in future be able to use the full functionality of `journalctl` for example, to see information from the boot before the current one

```
journalctl -b -2
```

See [the relevant page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Journal) of the wonderful <3 Arch Wiki <3 for further tips and tricks on using `journalctl`

Comment: As I said, `dmesg` might not show boot time info any more (if it is out of the kernel ring buffer already). But `journalctl -k` seems to be complete.

Comment: Also note that timestamps in `journalctl -k` output are not consistent with time offsets in `dmesg` output. In my case `dmesg` is showing a ~30 second delay during boot which `journalctl -k` does not between the same two log lines.

Comment: So you say `journalctl -k` is completley equivalent to `dmesg`?